# magento2, position of the custom attribute in product page

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I would like to display my custom `attribute` name **"teaser"** after the short description.

Below in `catalog_product_view.xml` didn't work.

```
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
 <body>
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.teaser" as="product.teaser" template="product/view/teaser.phtml" after="product.info.overview">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">teaser</argument>
        </arguments>             
     </block>
   </referenceBlock>        
 </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give `referenceContainer"product.info.main"` instead of **product.info.details**

```
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
 <body>
   <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.teaser" as="product.teaser" template="product/view/teaser.phtml" after="product.info.overview">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">teaser</argument>
        </arguments>             
     </block>
   </referenceContainer>        
 </body>
</page>
```